# Создание домена приложения и подгрузка dll

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

При создании домена приложения и подгрузке dll возникает исключение `FileNotFoundExcption` с текстом `Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "MyLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.`
Код приложения:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
        setup.ApplicationBase = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "MyApplication");

        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), null, setup);

        string dllPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "MyApplication", "MyLibrary.dll");

        AssemblyName name = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dllPath);

        Assembly asm = domain.Load(name); //Возникает исключение

        Type[] asmTypes = asm.GetTypes();

        AppDomain.Unload(domain);
    }
```

Код MyLibrary.dll:

```
namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class MyMath
    {
        public int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

Не знаю в чём проблема, файл dll есть в каталоге приложения, но почему выкидывает исключение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, проблема в `GetCurrentDirectory()`. Текущий каталог — совсем не обязательно тот, где лежит ваша программа.

[Попробуйте вместо этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837501/276994)

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Comment: Но ведь на выходе я получу одну и ту же строку

Comment: @Алексей: Не-а. Если вы, например, запускаете программу с рабочего стола, текущий каталог — это рабочий стол, а не каталог, где лежит программа. Ну и из-под Visual Studio тоже наверняка рабочим каталогом будет каталог проекта, а не /bin/x64.

Comment: но мне требуется загрузить dll из специфичного каталога.

Comment: @Алексей: Это понятно. Но этот каталог, скорее всего, не имеет никакого отношения к возвращаемому `GetCurrentDirectory()` значению. Вы бы лучше воспользовались отладчиком и посмотрели, какое значение возвращают оба метода, и какое из них правильное.